# How can I fix this overflow issue in IE7 with the absolutely positioned container?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, fluid-layout

I have created a layout which works well in IE8+ but not in IE7. The problem is, the absolutely positioned #container (which has a top to push it below the header and a bottom of zero to fill the body) fills the entire content length in ie7 rather than only fill the body.

I have setup a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TPNpy/97/ to show what's happening and would really appreciate any help.

Setting the height using javascript for ie7 is my last resort, and i'm not convinced this is the only way.

Thanks

It would be easier to have a look at the code in jsfiddle, but here is the basic structure and CSS:

```
#container { background-color: #333; width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0; top: 80px; }
#sidebar { background-color: #333; width: 170px; height: 100%; float: left; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto; }
#content { background-color: #F9F9F9; height: 100%; margin-left: 170px; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto; }

<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    Sidebar Content (which allows scrolling when very long)
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    Main Content (which allows scrolling when very long)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is using DTD HTML5, which will probably correspond to quirks mode in IE7.  You may need a hack of sorts, although a IE conditional CSS would be a good option.

Comment: i don't have IE 7 here right now, so i can't say for sure. but if i remember right IE 7 is not able to set `100%` height with position `relative`  correctly in this situation. so you have to use `absolute` position for `#sidebar` and `#content`

Comment: Thanks very much @t.niese! Adding absolute positioning to #sidebar and #content fixed it. How should I submit your answer? ...new to this

Comment: @kingjubba Seems like he is not adding it as an answer, so you could write the answer yourself and accept it, so this question does not show up anymore in the Unanswered list :). Or simply delete the question.